# Stack changed a text/quote block

Tags: discussion

What happened to the quote block on this website that used ">"? I remember it had a yellowish block. But now when I use it I see a grey bar

> like this

I don't like this aesthetic very much, so I was wondering if anyone knew how I can use the old one if it's still an option.

Comment: this should be asked on meta not here I hadn't noticed but they seem to have changed the style... (won't be under the control of this site

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/343919, apparently it is an improvement.

Comment: @moewe -- I would represent that as "improvement".  Not.  There are now multiple things in grey boxes or with grey bars, not always well distinguished from one another: quotes, code blocks, I've forgotten what the other is.